# Java/Spring Soap requests

Tags: java, spring, soap, jaxb, openfeign

Please tell me the library for working with soap requests in the context of java / spring ?

Tried jaxb for unmarshalling but having problems with namespaces

```java
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
```